# Are there any answer key of Dummit & Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I am trying to solve Abstract Algebra of David S. Dummit & Richard M. Foote. Almost most of the problems are statement proving type. But now I have found some counting, precisely speaking numerical answer type questions such as find out the number of prime ideals of the given ring etc. There are millions of problems of this book which are still unsolved by me. So I need a answer key to verify my work ,specialy numerical answer type questions.  I have searched in Google but what I get is very naive and solved very few problems. Please provide me any accessible link of answer key , Now I am doing exercise  9.2 , so for now it's enough to get 9.2 answer key only if the whole answer key is currently unavailable.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: *There are millions of problems of this book which are still unsolved.* I think this is somewhat of an exaggeration...

Comment: @YiFan I'm saying for myself. I haven't solved many problems , Ok! I'm editing it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is an important question. Dummit & Foote is one of the better (best?) introductory algebra texts out there, so it's good if we can find an answer key for it (and a pity if we can't).

Comment: Could you please state the problem here?

Comment: @Wuestenfux 1) Describe the ring structure of $Z [x,y]/ <x^2,y^2,2> $ 2)Determine all the ideals of the ring  $Z[x]/<2,x^3+1> $

Comment: @Wuestenfux the 1st problem is definitely not integral domain as $x×x=x^2 \in <x^2,y^2,2> $. $I /<x^2,y^2,2>$ are all ideals of it. Where  $I $ are $<x>, <y>,<x^2>, <y^2>, <x,y>, <x^2,y>, <x,y^2>, <x^2,y^2>, <x,y,2>, <x^2,y,2>, <x,y^2,2>, <2>, <x,2>, <y,2>,Z [x,y], <x^2,y^2,2> $

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is either too broad, or asking for access to possibly copyrighted material. I can't decide which???

Comment: @Wuestenfux 2nd problem;  there are four ideals of it. $Z (x)/<2,x^3+1> ~ Z (x)/<2>/<2,x^3+1>/<2>~Z_2 (x)/<x^3+1> $ by using 3rd Isomorphism theorem. Thus we have four ideals $I/<x^3+1> $, $I=<x+1>/ <x^2-x+1>,/<x^3+1>/Z_2 (x) $

Comment: Nope, $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, but $x^2-x+1=(x-2)^2$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux so there are another ideal $<x-2>/<x^3+1>$?

Answer (score 1):

1) Looks like ${\Bbb Z}_2[x,y]/\langle x^2,y^2\rangle$ with generating set $1,x,y,xy$.

2) Hint: The ideals of ${\Bbb Z}_2[x]/\langle x^3+1\rangle$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the ideals of ${\Bbb Z}_2[x]$ containing $\langle x^3+1\rangle$ (by one of the isomorphism theorems for rings).

Comment: I guess my 2nd answer is correct. Isn't it?

Comment: for the 1st problem  $I/<x^2,y^2>$ are the ideals of the given ring .where  
 $I = <x>, <y>, <x,y>, <x^2,y>, <x,y^2>,Z_2 (x,y), <x^2,y^2> $